# Remove "Log In" header from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

[image]

This header shows up on my website when not signed in. Is there anyway to get rid of it for visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

https://cpothemes.com/disable-wordpress-admin-bar

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

To remove WordPress Admin Bar, you can edit your child theme's `functions.php` file.

By adding those lines of code Admin Bar will be only visible to connected Admin

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
       show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```